# Sigkill error: training Mask RCNN model on custom dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

I am trying to train Mask-RCNN model on custom dataset. But, after few seconds my program stops with "exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9 sigkill)" error.

Answer (score 0):

This error occur when our model is using excessive memory. Setting small batch size will help.

Comment: I have tried with batch size of 1, but it is still giving the same error

Comment: Try running it on Google Colab with GPU, maybe it would work there.

Comment: I am running the model on Azure VM. Can you please help me in finding the bug on the VM itself